# Converting a function to accept input directly in r

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I was reading a book and I came across this function in R. This function basically finds out patterns in the input string having a minimum threshold of 3.

```
vec <- "da0abcab0abcaab0d0"

find_rep_path <- function(vec, reps) {
  regexp <- paste0(c("(.+)", rep("\\1", reps - 1L)), collapse = "")
  match <- regmatches(vec, regexpr(regexp, vec, perl = TRUE))
  substr(match, 1, nchar(match) / reps)
}

vals <- unique(strsplit(vec, "")[[1]])
str <- NULL
for (i in seq.int(nchar(vec))) {
  x <- vec
  for (v in vals) {
    substr(x, i, i) <- v
    tmp <- find_rep_path(x, 3)
    if (length(tmp) > 0)
      str <- c(str, tmp)
  }
}

nc <- nchar(str)
unique(str[which(nc == max(nc))])
```

Now, I wish to convert this function into the form like,
function("da0abcab0abcaab0d0"). This means, that I can easily pass a string to the function directly and not hardcode it in the original function. How can I modify this? 
I know this is a beginner question but I am completely at sea right now as far as R is concerned. Please help!

Comment: It is not hardcoded, try: `find_rep_path("da0abcab0abcaab0d0",2)`

Comment: But, it doesn't give the desired output. It gives only "a". As opposed to what I should get.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how it's hardcoded. But you can just wrap your code into a function if that's what you mean?

```
# Function 1
find_rep_path <- function(vec, reps) {
  regexp <- paste0(c("(.+)", rep("\\1", reps - 1L)), collapse = "")
  match <- regmatches(vec, regexpr(regexp, vec, perl = TRUE))
  substr(match, 1, nchar(match) / reps)
}

# Function 2
foo <- function(vec) {
  vals <- unique(strsplit(vec, "")[[1]])
  str <- NULL
  for (i in seq.int(nchar(vec))) {
    x <- vec
    for (v in vals) {
      substr(x, i, i) <- v
      tmp <- find_rep_path(x, 3)
      if (length(tmp) > 0)
        str <- c(str, tmp)
    }
  }
  nc <- nchar(str)
  return(unique(str[which(nc == max(nc))])) 
}

vec <- "da0abcab0abcaab0d0"
foo(vec)
#[1] "0ab" "abc"
```

**Edit1**

To get the place of the matches you can use `gregexr`:

```
 a <- foo(vec)
 gregexpr(a[1], vec)
 #[[1]]
 #[1] 3 9
 #attr(,"match.length")
 #[1] 3 3
 #attr(,"useBytes")
 #[1] TRUE
```

This tells you that `a[1]` (`"0ab"`) was matched in `vec` at positions 3 and 9. Run `?gregexpr` for more informations.

**Edit2**

To add this information to each match, we can do something like

```
bar <- function(vec) {
  m <- foo(vec)
  ans <- sapply(m, gregexpr, vec, fixed = TRUE)
  ans <- lapply(ans, function(x) {attributes(x) <- NULL; x})
  return(ans)
}
bar(vec)
#$`0ab`
#[1] 3 9
#
#$abc
#[1]  4 10
```

Comment: No, it shows the error.
    Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion /   options(expressions=)?
    Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite   recursion / options(expressions=)?

Comment: @user3769571 Try to restart R and run only the code in my answer. It should not yield an error. Not for me at least.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly fine. Thanks again. :)
Also, is there a chance that you can tell me, how can I add the starting position. That is, "0ab" is a pattern which starts from the second position and "abc" is a pattern starting from 3 position.

Comment: Yup, that works but can I make it something like, I get all of it when I run the function with the input, i.e., I get, 
0ab abc 3 9. All of it in a single row and at once. Thanks!

Comment: @user3769571 Just wrap it into another function. I'll leave that exercise for you :)

Comment: Hi! I tried making it into another function. However, I am having a small doubt, how do I access the particular the list containing 3 and 9. I did this, b <- gregexpr(a[1],vec), and then, b[[1]] but it shows again the same original gregexpr list.

Comment: I will append the row containing the starting positions to the original pattern.

Comment: @user3769571 You cannot simply just append it. First, because then the matching postions will be coerced to a `character`. Second, because there are multiple matching postions per pattern you can't tell which match is from where. I.e. the output `0ab abc 3 9` is wrong. `0ab` is matched a positions 3 and 9, not `abc`. I've edited my post with a suggesting on how to do it.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. That works, but I want only the starting positions, and not the parametres such as length and use bytes. How do I actually associate only the starting position?

Comment: @user3769571 Final help from me. I've edited the post, again :)